# Nested JSON as Request parameters with URLRequestConvertible protocol (Alamofire)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, alamofire

Alamofire has provided a very handy protocol URLRequestConvertible with which I can manage my REST api in more managed way by creating a router class.

Everything was working fine until I had to request a REST api with **Post method** where I had to pass nested **JSON as parameters** as following:-

```
{
    “studentID” : "297",
    “studentName” : “Jack”,
    “FilterValues” : [
      {
        “Field1” : “code”,
        “Field2” : “1234232”,
        “Field3” : “111”
      }
    ]
}
```

The problem I am facing is, the protocol works fine when I make Rest calls with basic JSON parameter as following:-

```
{
 “field1” : "jack",
 “field2” : “1233434”,
 "field3" : "test"
}
```

But when I had to make call with nested JSON, secondary JSON are ignored and treat the above parameters as following:

```
{
  “studentID” : "297",
  “studentName” : “Jack”,
  “FilterValues” : [

  ]
}
```

**Here is my router class:-**

```
class Router: URLRequestConvertible {

static let baseURL = "http://xxxxxx.com"

case login (username: String, password: String)
case studentList (studentID: String, studentName:String)

var method: HTTPMethod {
    return .post
}

var path: String {
    switch self {
    case .login:
        return "/login"
    case .studentList:
        return "/list"
    }
}


public func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {

    let parameters: [String: Any] = {
        switch self {
        case .login(let username, let password):
            return ["username": username, "password": password]
        case .studentList (let studentID, let studentName):
            return ["studentID": studentID, "studentName": studentName, "FilterValuess": [["Field1": "code", "Field2": "someValue", "Field3": "someValue"]]]
        default:
            return [:]
        }
    }()

    let url = try Router.baseURL.asURL()
    var request = URLRequest(url: url.appendingPathComponent(path))
    request.httpMethod = method.rawValue
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

//   request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type") Tried no success
//   request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters) Tried With JSONSerialization but no success.

    return try URLEncoding.default.encode(request, with: parameters as! Parameters)
 }
}
```

The login API works fine. But studentList no success, since Alamofire does not recognize JSON parameters.

Searched whole day through google for its solution but could not find one.
Then I tried with Alamofire another request api as following:-

```
    let parameters = ["studentID": studentID, "studentName": studentName, "FilterValuess": [["Field1": "code", "Field2": "someValue", "Field3": "someValue"]]] as [String: Any]
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://xxxxxx.com/list")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters)

    Alamofire.request(request)
        .responseString(completionHandler: { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
                if let data = response.data, let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                    print(responseString)
                }
            case .success(let responseObject):
                // Received desired output
                print(responseObject)
            }
        })
```

**This gives the desired output.** But I want to achieve result with URLRequestConvertible, since I don't want to handle every api differently. It would be great if my **Router** class which is subclass of **URLRequestConvertible** handle all my REST api.

My question is, is there any way I can send nested JSON as parameters in **Alamofire** using **URLRequestConvertible**?

**Any help is highly appreciable.**

Answer (score 1):

Change the last line

```
return try URLEncoding.default.encode(request, with: parameters as! Parameters)
```

to

```
return try JSONEncoding.default.encode(request, with: parameters)
```